# How can I check if the cluster has been initialized or not in Couchbase?

Tags: docker, couchbase

I have a docker-compose file to run a Couchbase container, but when the cluster has been initialized, and then stop and start again the container I have the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6loq.png)

my docker-compose.yml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hp33.png)

is there any way to check if the cluster is already initialized or not?.

Comment: Please dont upload images of code / errors / config, rather format your code using code blocks, or block quotes. Here is some background as to why not: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

The `couchbase-cli serverlist` command will succeed if the cluster initialized, and fail if it is uninitialized.

```
couchbase-cli server-list --username Administrator --password password --cluster localhost
```

Alternatively, you can inspect the result of this HTTP request:

```
curl http://localhost:8091/pools/default/ -u Administrator:password
```

Thank you to HouseHippo and omatrot who discussed this on the Couchbase Forum
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-cli-check-if-a-cluster-has-been-set-up/4936

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it), which is a script to wait until a host/port is available. You can include this in your own custom image.

Another possibility is taking a look at these [couchbasefakeit images.](https://github.com/brantburnett/couchbasefakeit) You may or may not want to use one of those images, but certainly you can look at the techniques used in them.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, I use `if [ ! -e "/nodestatus/initialized" ] ; ` and it works. I found it in the second link that you mentioned in one of the scripts..